# Realloc C string array heap corruption

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create dynamic string array to be the buffer for reading a file. The point is that the array must be declared with given size, but it's got to resize if file contains more lines than buffer size is. Buffer I've created looks like this:

```
#define N 32

char **array = (char**) malloc((N+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

When it comes to reallocation I've tried it this way:

```
array = (char**) realloc(array, (2*N+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

But unfortunately it causes heap corruption. How should I do it properly?

Comment: the problem might come for the fact that you use char** and not char*; If you are dynamically allocating memory for a 2D array, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: How should i do it to create dynamic array for strings?

Comment: There is no problem with using a char** if you want an array of strings. However, your reallocation will only work once (since the size is hard-coded) and the way you use realloc() doesn't handle failure correctly. Maybe there's a problem with how you set the strings themselves?

Comment: You did it properly, are you sure the heap corruption is on the `realloc` line?

Comment: Yes, thanks to Bit Fiddling Code Monkey I've found out lack of multiplication by 'numEntries' as he did. Now it's working.

Comment: You don't need to cast when you get values from memory allocation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two dimensions, like such:

```
char **array = malloc((N+1) * (numEntries) * sizeof(char));
```

Note I'm using `sizeof(char)`, not `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: You have probably forgot to put (char **) before malloc, but with your suggestion I've managed to make it. I didn't remember to insert multiplication by numEntries. Thank you.

Comment: be careful. you should only allocate array of pointers, you cant allocate two dimensions array, since the compiler don't know how to split the "lines", in some compilers as long as you accessing to array[0][x] everything is ok, but when you try to go to array[1][0] you'll have a problem, other compilers will fail accessing also array[0][0].

Comment: I doubt `char**` is correct. This should be `char (*array)[N+1] = ...` asuming `N+1` is the size of the strings to be stored in this array.